# DataGrid with templated RowHeader and ColumnHeader in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

How to create a grid with a templated RowHeader, ColumnHeader, and Cells?

The ViewModel can have a list of objects for RowHeader item display, a list of objects for ColumnHeader item display. Basically think of it like a matrix display.

Probably a ControlTemplate needs to be written, but running out of ideas. There's not much of a documentation on this functionality.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style for a DataGridColumnHeader or a DataGridRowHeader and set the ContentTemplate to a DataTemplate which allows the Header property to be bound. For this you need an IValueConverter which enables the binding.

The headers are in the Controls.Primitives namespace:

```
xmlns:dp="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```

Style:

```
        <Style TargetType="dp:DataGridColumnHeader" >
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource vcBC}}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Converter:

```
public class BindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType().Name == "Binding")
        {
            ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
            cc.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, value as Binding);
            return cc;
        }
        else return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Converter instance:

```
<yourassembly:BindingConverter x:Key="vcBC"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, helps partially but a whole lot of questions around the problem remain. Still looking...

Comment: Okay, so ask your remaining questions :-)